# Dark Colors are rendered Black

Tags: rendering, color

Darker colors are rendered black on my Blender and didn't experience this issue in my older version.

It started to happen after I updated it, I also use environment lightning with ambient set to black, I figured that could be the issue but I couldn't change it to anything else.

[image]

[image]

edit: also I could use some help with the weird color changes at the barrel

Comment: could you upload the blend file?

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)